# Running a jQuery function multiple times sequentially (for a Bookmarklet)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following jQuery code which I use in a Bookmarklet. It clicks on all the buttons on the page (with the class "Unfollow") one by one, with a random time between each one...

```
javascript: (function() {
    var unfollowButtons = $('button.Unfollow');
    var index = unfollowButtons.length - 1;
    unfollow();

    function unfollow() {
        if (index >= 0) {
            $(unfollowButtons[index--])
                .click();
            setTimeout(unfollow, Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 500));
        }
    }
})();
```

I'd like to run the above function again twice once it has completed its cycle.

Just running the function again causes that to run in parallel with the first function call.

How do I run the unfollow() function 2 or 3 times without them all running in parallel?

Comment: Can you use js global variable to track the run? If it is 3, do not create setTimeOut function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just reset `index` and restart after each button is clicked:

```
javascript: (function() {
    var unfollowButtons = $('button.Unfollow');
    var index = unfollowButtons.length - 1;
    var totalRuns = 3;
    unfollow();

    function unfollow() {
        if (index < 0 && totalRuns) {
            totalRuns--;
            unfollowButtons = $('button.Unfollow');
            index = unfollowButtons.length - 1;
        }

        if (index >= 0) {
            $(unfollowButtons[index--])
                .click();
            setTimeout(unfollow, Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 500));
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: This looked promising, but when it gets to 99 clicks it stops because index is undefined. I think this is happening when the if (!index && totalRuns) { condition is true.

Comment: Oh right, it should be `if (index < 0 && totalRuns)`.

Comment: Ah, cool. It almost works as it is. However, when it got to 100 it stops with an undefined error. So, I tried adding var unfollowButtons = $('button.Unfollow'); to the start of the unfollow() function and within the if (index < 0 && totalRuns) { condition and it works. Basically, the function needs to fetch a new set of 100 Unfollow buttons once the first 100 have been clicked. Could you update your answer with this and I'll mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks so much for your help! :-)

Comment: I updated it to update `unfollowButtons` during each iteration

Answer (score 6):

Try it this way (using [ES6 Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)):

```
var runUnfollow = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var index = unfollowButtons.length - 1;

    // fencepost for the loop
    var p = Promise.resolve();

    // we stop execution at `i == 0`
    for (var i = index; i >= 0; i--) {
      // run the promise
      // then set `p` as the next one
      p = p.then(unfollowTimeout.bind(null, i));
    }
    // make sure we run the last execution at `i == 0`.
    p.then(function(){
      resolve();
    })

    function unfollowTimeout(i){
      // return a promise to run `unfollow` and a `setTimeout`
      return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
         unfollow(i);
         setTimeout(resolve, Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 500));
      })
    }
    function unfollow(i) {
      $(unfollowButtons[i])
        .click();
    }
  })
}

// run three times synchronously
runUnfollow().then(runUnfollow).then(runUnfollow).then(function(){
  //finished
});

// another way to run three times synchronously
p = runUnfollow();
for(i=3; i > 0; i--){
  p = p.then(runUnfollow);
}
p.then(function(){
  //finished
});

// run in parallel
Promise.all([runUnfollow, runUnfollow, runUnfollow])
  .then(function(){
    //finished
  });
```

EDIT: Went back and read your question again, realized you were trying to run *everything* multiple times. I've edited to reflect that.

Comment: Looks interesting. Thanks. Unfortunately, I am getting an Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list on line 21. Do you know what that might be? Also, how can I set how many times to run the function?

Comment: fixed syntax issue. to set the number of times the function will run, just replace the value of `index` (line 6 above) with the number of times. i've also added additional comments, lines 3-5.

Comment: Promises are the way to go, although with Jquery present, you could also use JQuery Deferred objects, which probably have slightly nicer syntax than new Promise, but apart from that operate the same.

Comment: @EzraChu : in your `for` loop (`// another way to run three times synchronously`) : `p.then(...)` returns a new promise, you need to "update" p to actually *chain* the callbacks :  `p = p.then(runUnfollow)`

Comment: @EzraChu: Otherwise, you are just : calling 3 times in parallel `runUnfollow` once the first run has completed

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [`Promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Resolve your `Promise` at your function's execution's very end and call your function again. You should be good with that.

Comment: It looks interesting, but I'm struggling to understand the documentation and how I can modify my code to use Promises.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options

#### 1.Use a User Script

For that, you need a User Script extension manager, for example Tampermonkey for Chrome, Greasemonkey for Firefox, etc.

But since you want a bookmarklet, just leave it.

#### 2.Modify the Bookmarklet a little as follows

Add this code inside the `unfollow` function

That is check whether `index` reached 0 and also the flag is set or not.

`FLAG` is important otherwise it will create a infinitive recursion loop.

First set `FLAG` to 0 outside of `unfollow` function.

Then in `unfollow` function, if the `FLAG` is 0 and `index` is 0, initiate the next iteration and Set `FLAG` to 1.

```
if(index < 0 && FLAG==0){
      var unfollowButtons = $('button.Unfollow');
      FLAG=1;
      var index = unfollowButtons.length - 1;
      unfollow();
}
```

So, it will look like this.

```
javascript: (function() {
    var unfollowButtons = $('button.Unfollow');
    var index = unfollowButtons.length - 1;
    var FLAG=0;
    unfollow();

    function unfollow() {
        if (index >= 0) {
            $(unfollowButtons[index--])
                .click();
        if(index < 0 && FLAG==0){
             unfollowButtons = $('button.Unfollow');
             FLAG=1;
             index = unfollowButtons.length - 1;
             unfollow();
        }
            setTimeout(unfollow, Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 500));
        }
    }
})();
```

If you want to do it totally 3 times, change `if(index < 0 && FLAG<=2){` and `FLAG=1` to `FLAG +=1`

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! Unfortunately the code doesn't work as is. The unfollow, index and FLAG variables are undefined within the unfollow function, and I can't just move them to within the unfollow function otherwise it will loop forever.

Comment: define it outside and reassign value inside the function again. please check the code now @iagdotme

Comment: The function never ends up running properly because the if(index >= 0) statement in the unfollow() function is false - because index is undefined. But I can't reassign index or unfollowButtons because this will give us another 100 buttons and so function will run forever.

Comment: it is a double check `index <0 && FLAG==0`

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, you could simply build an array which contains twice each button :

```
// turn the jQuery selection into a regular array :
var unfollowButtons = $('button.Unfollow').get();

// build a new array, which contains two copies of the above selection :
unfollowButtons = unfollowButtons.concat(unfollowButtons);
```

Comment: On the page, there are 100 unfollow buttons. When each one is clicked, a new unfollow button appears. So there are always 100 buttons. I'd like the function to be called again once the first 100 buttons have been clicked - up to 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your requirements it can be done like this :

```
javascript: (function() {
    var unfollowButtons = $('button.Unfollow');
    var index = unfollowButtons.length - 1;
    unfollow();
    var runForNoOfTime = 3;
    var runningForTime = 1;
    function unfollow() {
        if (index >= 0) {
            $(unfollowButtons[index--]).click();
            setTimeout(unfollow, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 500));

        }else if(runningForTime < runForNoOfTime){
               runningForTime++;
               unfollowButtons = $('button.Unfollow'); //if buttons with class 'Unfollow' changes.
               index = unfollowButtons.length - 1;
               setTimeout(unfollow, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 500));
            }
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to achieve the desired effect of running your function multiple times sequentially. Here's how this can be done:

```
(function() {
    var unfollowButtons = $('button.Unfollow');
    var index = unfollowButtons.length - 1;

    function unfollow(callback) {
        if (index >= 0) {
            $(unfollowButtons[index--]).click();
        }

        callback();
    }

    function handleUnfollow(maxIter, iter) {
        iter = typeof iter === "number" ? iter : 0;

        if ( iter >= maxIter ) {
            // base case reached, stop further recursive calls
            return true;
        }

        // call unfollow once
        unfollow(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {

                // recursive call
                handleUnfollow(maxIter, ++iter);

            }, Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 500));
        });
    }

    // execute recursive function, which will iterate 2 times
    handleUnfollow(2);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware Javascript runs on a single thread, so there is no actual parallel processing taking place.

If you just simply want the function to run itself x times then use recursion:

```
function DoSomething(steps) {    
    // Do stuff here
    steps--;
    if (steps <== 0) {
        return;
    }
    DoSomething(steps);
}
```

If you want things to run in "parallel" with Javascript then perhaps you could look into having some external code that manages threads and executes multiple Javascript processes in parallel (although I'm not sure if this is possible, and, if it is, whether you'll be able to have the scripts accessing the same data at the same time or talking to eachother).

Answer (score 0):

I have made the current code as block and added wrapper logic. Check if this works.

```html
(function() {
  var iterations = 2;
  unfollowBlock();
  
  function unFollowBlock() {
    if (iterations-- >0) {
        var unfollowButtons = $('button.Unfollow');
        var index = unfollowButtons.length - 1;
        unfollow();

        function unfollow() {
            if (index >= 0) {
                $(unfollowButtons[index--])
                    .click();
                setTimeout(unfollow, Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 500));
            }
            else { //index=-1 end of unfollowblock
                setTimeout(unFollowBlock, Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 500));
            }
        }
     }
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a flag/check variable eg. var isCycleComplete;

```
var isCycleComplete = false;

if(isCycleComplete){ // if true runs unfollow function twice
 unfollow();
 unfollow(); 
 isCycleComplete = false; // resets flag
}
else{ // if false
 unfollow();
 isCycleComplete = true; //sets flag to true
}
```

M not a pro at javascript but See if this simple snippet helps you.